# Cancel touchend if user touch drags

Tags: jquery, touch, drag

I have the following code inside doc ready that is used to hide a menu when the document (background) is clicked. This works fine. However, I need to cancel the hide if the user starts a drag - `touchstart`. So, if the user touches and 'releases' or un-touches, the menu hides. But if they touch and then start to drag to see more of the menu, the menu will stay visible. As it is now, I try and cancel the `touchend` if a `touchmove` is started, but this is not working. It still hides the menu. Any help here would be much appreciated.

```
var touchmove = false;
$(document).on('touchmove',function() {
    touchmove = true;
})

var click_or_touch = is_touch_divice ? 'touchend' : 'click'

$(this).on(click_or_touch, function() {

    if (touchmove == true) return false;

    if ($('.popup_item').is(':visible')) {

        $('.popup_item').hide();

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Maybe this can help you**

Setting variable to false

```
var isDrag = false;
```

Setting var to true ontouchmove

```
$("body").on("touchmove", function(){
  isDrag = true;
});
```

Your button

```
$("#button").on("touchend", function(){
      if (isDrag)
      return;

      // Your button actions here; do your magic
});
```

Resetting variable

```
$("body").on("touchstart", function(){
    isDrag = false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan - I thought this would never get answered ;)